# Multiple routes same search input

Tags: angularjs

I have multiples views but the same search input on a navbar, the question is: **How use the input in the navbar to update data in view1Ctrl , View2Ctrl or anyCtrl**

**------- EDIT 1 -------**
My question was not specific

**I want to use the input in the navbar to update data in view1Ctrl , View2Ctrl or anyCtrl and how the controller knows if the serch input is used?**

In the real code i have a service that calls a $http get function and uptate the and on success update the array

```
$scope.loadMore = function() {
$scope.busy = true
data.all(page)
    .then(function success (response) {
        var data = response.data
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $scope.array1.push(data[i])
        }
        page++

        $scope.busy = false
    })
}

$scope.searchData = function (search) {
$scope.busy = true
$scope.array1 = [];
data.all(page, search)
    .then(function success (response) {
        var data = response.data
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $scope.array1.push(data[i])
        }
        page++

        $scope.busy = false
    })
}
```

I create a plnkr to clarify any doubts.

https://plnkr.co/edit/tENpWjPAzbV0GBg52L1V?p=preview

Thanks for help!

App.js

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider
    .otherwise("/home/view1");

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: "/home",
      templateUrl: "./home-main.html",
    })

  .state('home.view1', {
    url: "/view1",
    templateUrl: "./view1.html",
    controller: "view1Ctrl"
  })

  .state('home.view2', {
    url: "/view2",
    templateUrl: "./view2.html",
    controller: "view2Ctrl"
  })
})


app.directive('navbar', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl: './navbar.html',
    controller: 'view1Ctrl'
  }
})

app.controller('view1Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  $scope.search = ''

  $scope.onSearch = function() {
    console.log('calling onSearch')
    $scope.array1 = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]
  }
});

app.controller('view2Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  $scope.search = ''

  $scope.onSearch = function() {
    console.log('calling onSearch')
    $scope.array1 = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]
  }
});
```

Comment: Put your onSearch into a service and you can inject it to all controllers, google for angular services. Or you can create a controller for the navbar only and use it on every route

Comment: That was my first idea, but how the controller knows if the data change?

Answer (score 0):

try this nested view :

```
.state('home.nav', {
                    url: "/",

                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: './navbar.html',
                        controller: 'view1Ctrl'
                    }
                })
```

or you can use abstract :

```
.state('my-app', {
                      abstract: true,
                      views: {
                          'navtest': {
                              templateUrl: './pathTonav',
                              controller: "navcontroller"
                          }
                      }
                  })
```

and then you can add the new custom element to your root html page :

```
<div ui-view="navtest"><\div>
```

Comment: I want to use the input in the navbar to update data in view1Ctrl , View2Ctrl or anyCtrl

Answer (score 0):

```
app.directive('navbar', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl: './navbar.html',
    controller: 'navbarCtrl'
  }
});

app.controller('navbarCtrl', function($scope){
   //your search stuff
 }

<body ng-app='youreapp'>
     <navbar></navbar>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Something like that?

Comment: No, i have resolved this part if you check the plunker, i want to use the input in the navbar to update data in view1Ctrl or View2Ctrl